# How to multiply a row of values to a table with the same number of fields?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a row of value from A2:H2 and then I have a table of values from B7:E8 (both the table and row have 8 data points).

How do I go about multiplying them? Please see the bellow illustration:

```
+----+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|   |   A   |   B   |   C   |   D   |   E   |   F   |   G   |   H   |
+---+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| 1 |  A1   |  A2   |  B1   |  B2   |  C1   |  C2   |  D1   |  D2   |
| 2 |    1  |    2  |    3  |    4  |    5  |    6  |    7  |    8  |
| 3 |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |
| 4 |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |
| 5 |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |
| 6 |       |   A   |   B   |   C   |   D   |       |       |       |
| 7 |   1   |   0.1 |   0.3 |   0.5 |   0.7 |       |       |       |
| 8 |   2   |   0.2 |   0.4 |   0.6 |   0.8 |       |       |       |
+---+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

I'm trying to multiply A2*B7, B2*B8, and so on with formulas because I don't want to hardcode (I have a lot of data points, this is just a sample for me to understand the concept). The goal is to output a single row =A2*B7, =B2*B8, =C2*C7, =C2*C*,.... and so on

Comment: And then what? Do you want `B8` to be *changed to* `0.4` and `C7` to be *changed to* `0.9`, etc? Do you want the results to be written to some other range that contains eight cells? (And will that always be 8×1 or 4×2, or might it be 2×4 or 8×1?) Or do you want to ***add*** 0.1+0.4+0.9+…?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the products in Row 17, from `A17` to `H17`, enter

```
=A2*INDEX($B$7:$E$8, MOD(COLUMN()-1,2)+1, INT((COLUMN()-1)/2)+1)
```

into `A17` and drag/fill right. 
To start in some other column,
replace the two occurrences of `-1` in the above formula
with your starting column number. 
For example, to use `G17:N17`, use `-7` instead of `-1`.